# simplest non-raid way of pooling nvme ssd drives on a single node - glusterfs?

Tags: raid, video-editing, glusterfs

We are putting together a RHEL OS video editing server which is fully nvme-ssd based. It needs to be high thoughput and very low latency. RAID controllers kill the speeds. Commercial software RAID (xiRAID) is available and in our tests works well. However, I don't see the need for the complexity and inflexibility of RAID when individual disks are fast enough to have full files on individual drives. Unraid and MergerFS look good, but our management is not happy to base a production server on a one-man open source project.

How about GlusterFS? I can't find any references to people running this on a single node. We don't want a distributed file system, we just want pooled storage on a single node with optionally some parity for redundancy.

Comment: I think it is a myth that hardware raid slows things down (unless you buy cheap hw raid).  The truth is that parity slows things down because it forces all the disks to operate synchronously.    So you get either speed (raid 0, raid1) or reliability (raid 5, raid 6), and it is irrelevant if you use hardware raid or software raid.  Note that raid5 still gives you higher bandwidth than a single disk, but it gives you iops of only a single disk.

Comment: Have you tried [ZFS](https://openzfs.org/wiki/Main_Page) pools or even [ZFS Raid](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Basic%20Concepts/RAIDZ.html)? It does all the raid dirty-work for you with 1, 2, or 3 disk parity, and is easy to manage. I'm not sure about performance: you would have to evaluate that for your particular application.

Answer (score 2):

GlusterFS seems like a pretty bad choice; you need none of the features it brings (that's why nobody uses it on single nodes, it makes no sense), and you get all of the performance and complexity downsides.

That's practically *the* classical use case for logical volume management, as implemented on modern Linux by LVM2; define a group of volumes, add each of your physical NVMes as physical volumes to that, and create one (or as many as you like) logical volumes on that, and use really any file system you like. Overhead is in my tests negligible, and it literally takes 3 command line actions to set up:

1. You want to combine `/dev/nvmeA`, `/dev/nvmeB`, …, `/dev/nvmeX`. So, you create a volume group (called "swamigroup", pick as you like) out of them (WILL REMOVE EXISTING DATA ON THESE DEVICES): 
   `sudo vgcreate swamigroup /dev/nvmeA /dev/nvmeB /dev/nvmeC` … `/dev/nvmeX`.
2. Create a logical volume called "datavol" on that group using up 100% of the available space:
    `sudo lvcreate -l '100%FREE' -n datavol swamigroup`
3. Create a file system on that, of your choice. I picked ext4 here, pick what works best for you. 
   `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/swamigroup-datavol`

That's it. Done. You can now mount `/dev/mapper/swamigroup-datavol`, add it to your `/etc/fstab`, …

If you want to add a new device, say, `/dev/nvmeY`, to the group

1. set it up as physical volume, `sudo pvcreate /dev/nvmeY`,
2. add it to the existing volume group, `sudo vgextend swamigroup /dev/nvmeY`

You then often would want to actually also make the logical volume use that newly found free space, `sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE -r`, where `-r` means that the underlying filesystem's resize utility (here, `resize2fs`) gets called automatically. This can all be done during full operation.

LVM can do a lot more things (*including* software RAID, snapshots, thin volumes, replacement of failing disks during operation, …), but then we're necessarily getting into "you'll need to read a `man` page" complexity, and my impression was that you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: I guess the most useful extra bells and whistles would be to make the volume striped over all disks: `lvcreate --stripes 4 --stripesize 1M ...` or whatever would be useful. Needs benchmarks of course.

Comment: I'm doing that, actually, on one of my workstations for compile workloads; it didn't pay off very well, but that's probably because I'm more limited by iops than by sequential read speed. Now I'm stuck with the problem that I can't figure out how to cycle out any of the involved SSDs as soon they start aging; I must admit I'm not sure I thought that through very well. Or actually, I'm kind of surprised that I can't find a way to reduce a PV backing a striped LV...

Answer (score 0):

You might look at filesystems that support multi-volume directly, like [btrfs](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Volume-management.html). Also, you can use `dmsetup` to directly map 2 block devices into one. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmsetup) has an example table.

There are performance suggestions from [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/performance_tuning_guide/index#sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Configuration_tools-Configuring_file_systems_for_performance) for your filesystem.